# Is it possible to use custom attributes on <content> nodes in Polymer for a beautiful API?

Tags: javascript, polymer

How would I implement a custom element API like:

```
<swiper-slider>
  <slide background="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-9.jpg"></slide>
  <slide>JUST TEXT!</slide>
</swiper-slider>
```

in Polymer? I can't seem to figure out how to check if `background` has been set on the `slide` node using JavaScript or how to use that attribute.

The closest I have gotten is `data-background="..."` with `nodes[ i ].dataset.background` where nodes is `nodes = this.$.content.getDistributedNodes()`.

Any insights greatly appreciated, especially if the verdict is that this is not possible!

Comment: `if( element.hasAttribute('background') ){src = element.getAttribute('background')}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through the childNodes and check the element:

```
...
ready: function() {
 for(var i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
  var element = this.childNodes[i];

  if(element.tagName == "SLIDE") {
   switch(true) {
    // Credit here goes to John Smith, btw!
    case element.hasAttribute("background"): 
     var background = element.getAttribute("background");
     break;

    default:
     break;
   }
  }
}
...
```

Comment: you can also use a this.querySelectorAll("slide") to get all slide elements

Comment: Thank you all! `this.querySelectorAll("slide")` + `for ( ; i < this.slides.length; i++ )` + `slide.hasAttribute('background');` did the trick.